# amcharts.js - make guide lines visible, if values are too different

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I need something like in the picture attached.
[image: I need something like this]Please follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haykaghabekyan/pznjwubk/)

As you can see, I've added two guide lines, but they are not visible, as its values are bigger than graph values.. Is there any way, I can make them visible? Maybe there is some way to zoom chart out or something.. See my code bellow or in jsfiddle.
Thanks,

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "date": "2012-01-01",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-02",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-03",
        "value": 12
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-04",
        "value": 14
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-05",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-06",
        "value": 6
    }, {
        "date": "2012-01-07",
        "value": 7
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "tickLength": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "bullet": "none",
        "valueField": "value"
    }],
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0.1,
    },
  "guides": [{
    "value": 25,
    "toValue": 25,
    "lineColor": "#CC0000",
    "fillAlpha": 1,
    "fillColor": "#CC0000",
    "label": "critical"
  }, {
    "value": 20,
    "toValue": 20,
    "lineColor": "#CCF000",
    "fillAlpha": 1,
    "fillColor": "#CCF000",
    "label": "normal"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a value axis setting [`includeGuidesInMinMax`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#includeGuidesInMinMax). Just set it to `true` and it will recalculate value axis scale to include all present guides:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "axisAlpha": 0,
  "position": "left",
  "tickLength": 0,
  "includeGuidesInMinMax": true
}]
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/pznjwubk/1/).